# Is there a way to create a FXML/Javafx desktop app without Netbeans, eclipse or scene builder?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

I'm looking to get started with javafx and fxml, without downloading netbeans (as the official docs suggests: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm), eclipse or scenebuilder. I'm looking to use a simple text editor and terminal, similar to the way someone might create an html,css and javascript project. Is this possible, or is the only way to use fxml and javafx through netbeans or some other similar tool?

Comment: To be honest, I think it would be much easier to develop it in an IDE. May I ask why you don't want to use one?

Comment: Oh ok :) After doing some research, I couldn't find anywhere that showed how to run JavaFX using something other than an IDE. You'll need a GUI to display your JavaFx code

Comment: short answer: personal preference
long answer: with every new language/skillset (android applications, websites, ios applications, etc) people tell me to download this ide or that ide - but I've pretty much stuck with sublime and my terminal for the most part (unless I have to deviate - for things like emulators/simulators) and it's worked fine. It seems not many people do this for fxml/javafx though or perhaps no tutorials/documentation that I have found so far have explained how to do so.

Comment: @mdash1 When starting out with new technology, use the recommended tools.  When you know what you are doing, you know what you need to do from the command line.     You may consider learning at least one full Java IDE well - the assistance an IDE that understands your code can give you is well worth the effort.

Comment: Did you mean ,you want use an editor not an full IDE ?

Answer (score 4):

Technically speaking, in any programming language, IDE is **always** *optional*.

You can write all your source codes (`.java`, `.css`, `.fxml`) files using any text editor that you like (like Notepad++), then go to a command-line interface (i.e. terminal, command prompt etc) and compile them, pretty much like how you would compile a Swing application.

The advantages of doing so? Pretty much simply because you can do this without any *unnecessary* downloads.

The disadvantages? You have to be VERY VERY clear on every single details about Java and JavaFX.

1. You need to be extremely familiar with building and compiling Java applications manually. You need to do your own build path in order to compile right.
2. There is nothing there that will instantly tell you that you have made a mistake (be it minor or major, or even a typo). You will only see where went wrong after you re-compile via command-line.
3. You have to do your imports manually (in both java and fxml). This means that you would have to know the *exact* package names and class names.
4. Most of the time, you would have to imagine how your application would look like visually. The only time if you know you designed right is when you re-compile and run it via command-line.

HTML, CSS, Javascript are considered *scripting language*. This means that these codes do not require code compilation, and that there is a base application/process that is running in the background to interpret what you wrote in English terms (or at least it is very close to English).

Languages like Java are true *programming language*, they require you to compile them, and running them will most likely create a new process on the OS.

So the conclusion is, it is definitely possible to do so, but you would probably end up using 10x (if not 100x) more time doing the same thing. IDE is there to help you do some of the tedious things. If you really want to do it using the traditional command-line method, ask a new question on that.